# on scroll moving the content div and then fix its position at bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I have a two column layout, where the sidebar's height is greater than the content thus leaving white space on bottom....

I want the content div to stick at bottom once full content is revealed while scrolling. My content div is inside a wrapper div

Here is the live test page online
[Check live page here](http://nuccadoctor.com/newtest/)

Please try to write jQuery code using my css classes and see if there is any css declaration issues causing the problem....

Comment: I don't think anyone is just going to do it for you. Here is the gist of what you need to do. Get the height of the div and when you scroll to the height equivalent, add a class that that will fix the divs position.

Comment: It is giving a height of null in my case as my layout is in %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a jquery plugin scrolltoFixed to fix the right content div and scroll the left sidebar

http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following updated to your html and css:

1. replace  with ul element and all children  in this part of HTML
2. apply the following style:

   #basic-page
   {
       position: fixed;
       right: 0;
   }
3. remove the left: 0px from css class ".content-wrapper"